# Using DataTrigger for TextBlock HorizontalAlignment property

Tags: wpf, xaml, text

On my `Grid` I Have `TextBlock` and `Button`. 
If `Button` is not visible I want my `TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment` to be set to `Center`. 
If `Button` is visible I want my `TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment` to be set to `Right`. Here is my code:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="myTextBlock" Text="{Binding TileTextId}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" >
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myButton, Path=IsVisible}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

I get the error:

> 'HorizontalAlignment' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name.

So I tried to add `TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment`, like this:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="myTextBlock" Text="{Binding TileTextId}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" >
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myButton, Path=IsVisible}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

I get the error:

> XamlParseException

How should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to use `TextBlock.Triggers`, instead go for a `Style` with `Style.Triggers`.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="TextBlock Content" Margin="5">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myButton,Path=IsVisible}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
    <Button x:Name="myButton" Content="Click Me!" Margin="5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Take note of [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.triggers(v=vs.110).aspx), as it mentions, why style triggers are needed here.

> Note that the collection of triggers established on an element only
>   supports EventTrigger, not property triggers (Trigger). If you require
>   property triggers, you must place these within a style or template and
>   then assign that style or template to the element either directly
>   through the Style property, or indirectly through an implicit style
>   reference.

Comment: Thanks. What is the reason my solution (without style) didn't work? What does the first error mean?

Comment: @Gabriel added this aspect to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this with Style

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="myTextBlock" Text="{Binding TileTextId}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" >
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myButton, Path=IsVisible}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```